# How to add break tag for createElement using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I created form elements in RecactJS but the elements are coming horizontally in the form.I want to apply break tags between the form elements.

return (
      React.createElement('form', {className: 'Contact'},
        React.createElement('input', {
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'First Name (required)',
          //value: this.props.value.name,
        }),

```
    React.createElement('input', {
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Last Name',
      //value: this.props.value.email,
    }),

    React.createElement('input', {
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Email',
      //value: this.props.value.description,
    })
```

Comment: What about showing some come? Are you sure this is about React or more about CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Apply break tags between the form elements.

```
<div>
  <FormElement />
  <br />
  <FormElement />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Skay thnx for the quick reply.I din't use FormElement tags.

Comment: FormElement is just the tag you want, you can put the tag name you want `Foo`, `div` or `input` if you like

Comment: @NarasingarajuMamidipaka Yes FormElement is just a placeholder. Replace it with what you have.